# Solutions of a linear system in RREF

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was given a reduced row echelon matrix that corresponds to this system:

$0x_1 + x_2 + 0x_3 = 7$

$0x_1 + 0x_2 + x_3 = 2$

That is, the first two elements of each row were 0.

The question was, determine the leading and free variables and find the solution set.

So, technically, $x_1$ is a free variable, but the system essentially is

$x_2 + 0x_3 = 7$

$0x_2 + x_3 = 2$

Then, can I still call $x_1$ a free variable? And, if so, the solution set will be ($x_1$, 7, 2), for all $x_1$ in **R**, or just (7, 2)?

Answer (score 1):

The augmented matrix describing our system is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0 & 1 & 0 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
The pivots in the coefficient matrix correspond to the variables $x_2$ and $x_3$. This means that $x_2$ and $x_3$ are the "dependent" variables and $x_1$ is the "free" variable.

The solutions to the system are given by
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
7 \\
2
\end{array}\right]
= x_1\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]
+\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
7 \\
2
\end{array}\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

The pivot columns are the columns corresponding to $x_2$ and $x_3$, and thus these two variables are so-called basic variables. Variables that are not basic are called free variables. In this case, as $x_1$ doesn't correspond to a pivot column, it is a free variable. The solution of this system of linear equations is specified by three variables, so we would write $(x_1,7,2)$ for any $x_1\in \mathbb{R}$.